# Initialization script not executed when container is run in detached mode

Tags: django, postgresql, shell, docker, dockerfile

I have a Dockerfile that builds a Django environment, which is based on an Ubuntu image and runs Apache HTTP Server. (httpd) Let's call that image `backend_image`. Along with another container for the PostgreSQL database, I plan to use this image as the development environment, firing both containers up and using the `--network` flag to connect them.

I planned to have an initialization script within the `backend_image`, which creates the relevant tables whenever the backend container is run. The contents of the script is rather standard for a Django app, and are as follows.

```bash
#!/bin/bash
source ${VIRTUAL_ENV_DIR}/bin/activate
python ${SCRIPT_LOCATION} makemigrations library
python ${SCRIPT_LOCATION} migrate
deactivate
```

This script is run correctly when I run the `backend_image` in the foreground. (i.e. without the `-d` flag in the `docker run` command) I checked it by connecting to the database container using `psql`, and `\dt` command printed the relevant databases.
However, in order to orchestrate the running of multiple containers required by the project, I need to run them in the detached mode. (I have a shell script running the containers, and connecting them) The problem is, when I run the backend container in detached mode, the tables are not created in the database container.

Below is the `CMD` of the Dockerfile of the `backend_image`.

```
CMD ["/bin/bash", "-c", "/tmp/initialization/initialize-db.sh && apachectl -D FOREGROUND"]
```

Like I said, if the container is run in the foreground, the script works and the relevant tables are created in the database container. Similarly, if I use the `docker run` command on the `backend_image` by overriding the `CMD` (i.e. specifying `/bin/bash` on the command line) and run the script manually from within the container, it is executed successfully. But somehow, when run in detached mode with `-d` flag, the script does not seem to create the tables in the PostgreSQL database. (as far as I can observe by connecting to the database container through `psql` and printing the relations by `\dt` command)

Note that the `apachectl` command seems to be running, and the server (along with the Django app) seems accessible, even when the backend container is run in detached mode. The only issue seems to be that the relevant tables are not created in the database container. It seems like the initialization script is never run in detached mode, as if portion of the `CMD` command before the `&&` is somehow ignored when the container is run in detached mode.

Is the problem with the initialization script? (or the way I execute it through `CMD` of the Dockerfile of `backend_image`) Or is there something I am missing about the detached mode, which keeps the script from being executed?

Comment: Often issues like this happen if the application starts before the database is fully ready; is that a possibility here?  If you add `set -x` to the initialization script to cause it to exit on error, does it actually run successfully?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the time I got this kind of errors, that was because my database was not ready yet. To have an idea of what's going on, you can log in your shell your web service:

```sh
docker-compose logs your-web-service -f # if you use docker-compose
```

Here is one solution I have in all of my `entrypoint.sh` scripts to wait for the database to initialize before using it:

```sh
while ! nc -vz my_db 5432;
    do
        if [ "$MY_DB_NOT_READY_DISPLAYED" != "yes" ]
        then
            echo "my_db not ready (wait for it...)";
            MY_DB_NOT_READY_DISPLAYED="yes"
        fi
        sleep 2;
    done;
echo my_db ready;
```

We try to connect to the database. If it works, good! If not, we display once that database is not ready, and then we try again every 2 seconds.

Maybe try to see if waiting for you database solve it? I also have this change of behavior between containers launched at foreground or background.

Comment: This seems to be the problem indeed. I tried checking by waiting a few seconds before running the backend container, and the database tables were created. (i.e. initialization script ran successfully) Your implementation presents a neat checking mechanism. Thanks!